# Avoid or remove lock from StgOpenStorage()

Tags: c#, winapi, com

Greets,

I found a similar question at [Opening OLE Compound Documents read-only with StgOpenStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086814/opening-ole-compound-documents-read-only-with-stgopenstorage) but that solution didn't work for me.

I try to open an outlook .msg file with StgOpenStorage(). My problem is, that StgOpenStorage always locks my file.

So, how can I avoid/remove the lock StgOpenStorage() adds to my file?

(see last method of code OpenStorage())

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

namespace IStorageLock
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000000d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IEnumSTATSTG
    {
        // The user needs to allocate an STATSTG array whose size is celt.
        [PreserveSig]
        uint Next(uint celt,
                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out]
                  System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG[] rgelt,
                  out uint pceltFetched);

        void Skip(uint celt);
        void Reset();

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
        IEnumSTATSTG Clone();
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000000b-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IStorage
    {
        void CreateStream(string pwcsName, uint grfMode, uint reserved1,
                          uint reserved2, out IStream ppstm);

        void OpenStream(string pwcsName, IntPtr reserved1, uint grfMode,
                        uint reserved2, out IStream ppstm);

        void CreateStorage(string pwcsName, uint grfMode, uint reserved1,
                           uint reserved2, out IStorage ppstg);

        void OpenStorage(string pwcsName, IStorage pstgPriority, uint grfMode,
                         IntPtr snbExclude, uint reserved, out IStorage ppstg);

        void CopyTo(uint ciidExclude, Guid rgiidExclude, IntPtr snbExclude,
                    IStorage pstgDest);

        void MoveElementTo(string pwcsName, IStorage pstgDest,
                           string pwcsNewName, uint grfFlags);

        void Commit(uint grfCommitFlags);

        void Revert();

        void EnumElements(uint reserved1, IntPtr reserved2, uint reserved3,
                          out IEnumSTATSTG ppenum);

        void DestroyElement(string pwcsName);

        void RenameElement(string pwcsOldName, string pwcsNewName);

        void SetElementTimes(string pwcsName,
                         System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME pctime,
                             System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME patime,
                             System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME pmtime);

        void SetClass(Guid clsid);

        void SetStateBits(uint grfStateBits, uint grfMask);

        void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG pstatstg,
                  uint grfStatFlag);
    }

    class Lock
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum STGM : int {
            DIRECT           = 0x00000000,
            TRANSACTED       = 0x00010000,
            SIMPLE           = 0x08000000,
            READ             = 0x00000000,
            WRITE            = 0x00000001,
            READWRITE        = 0x00000002,
            SHARE_DENY_NONE  = 0x00000040,
            SHARE_DENY_READ  = 0x00000030,
            SHARE_DENY_WRITE = 0x00000020,
            SHARE_EXCLUSIVE  = 0x00000010,
            PRIORITY         = 0x00040000,
            DELETEONRELEASE  = 0x04000000,
            NOSCRATCH        = 0x00100000,
            CREATE           = 0x00001000,
            CONVERT          = 0x00020000,
            FAILIFTHERE      = 0x00000000,
            NOSNAPSHOT       = 0x00200000,
            DIRECT_SWMR      = 0x00400000,
        }

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        private static extern int StgIsStorageFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                                   string pwcsName);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int StgOpenStorage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                         string       pwcsName,
                                         IStorage     pstgPriority,
                                         STGM         grfMode,
                                         IntPtr       snbExclude,
                                         uint         reserved,
                                         out IStorage ppstgOpen);

        public IStorage OpenStorage(string fileName)
        {
            if (StgIsStorageFile(fileName) != 0) {
                return null;
            }

            IStorage storage = null;

            //
            // StgOpenStorage() locks file 'fileName'
            //
            // Set flags like:
            // [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086814/opening-ole-compound-documents-read-only-with-stgopenstorage]
            //
            int stgOpenStorage = StgOpenStorage(fileName, null,
                                                STGM.READ            |
                                                STGM.SHARE_DENY_NONE |
                                                STGM.TRANSACTED,
                                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                                out storage);

            //
            // Try to rename file (for testing purposes only)
            //
            try {
                File.Move(fileName, fileName + @".renamed");
            } catch (Exception ex) {        // exception: file alreay in use by another process
                throw;
            }

            if (stgOpenStorage != 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return storage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Regards,

inno

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the file into memory and using StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes instead?

Comment: Any further hints? How to get file into memory so I can use it with StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes?

Comment: - Allocate a native memory block and get a HGLOBAL hanlde to it. It has to be moveable so you can't use Marshal.AllocHGlobal, got to use GlobalAlloc.
- Read the file into it whatever way you want. You can read from a rgular .NET FileStream and write the conntent with Marshal.Copy. Make sure you release the FileStream to remove all "locks" on the file.
- Call CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal to get the ILockBytes object.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem and the following code solved for me.  I have changed variable name to your example

```
storage.Commit(0);   // storage is a pointer to IStorage in OP's question
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(storage);
storage = null;

GC.Collect();
GC.Collect();  // call twice for good measure
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

This is based on Mirosoft sample code at [Extract embedded files from Office documents](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOfficeDocumentFileExtract-e5afce86) .

So in COM you need to [IUnknown.Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx) and reduce the reference count to zero so the object destroys itself deterministically but the whole [.NET/COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx) is not always as simple.  For [IStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380015(v=vs.85).aspx) it is probably better to call [IStorage.Commit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380016(v=vs.85).aspx) before calling [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx) which does [IUnknown.Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx) for you.  In the next line setting the variable to null explicitly helps mark the object for garbage collection which we then go on to call.  We call [GC.Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) twice because there are multiple generations of objects waiting for collection and because this is [Microsoft sample code.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOfficeDocumentFileExtract-e5afce86)  Lastly, another deterministic tidy up occurs on [GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks this helped me to resolve the StgOpenStorage issue. I am successfully releasing the com object by calling above code. I have commented Commit opearation. Like below 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//storage.Commit(0);   // storage is a pointer to IStorage in OP's question
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(storage);
storage = null;

GC.Collect();
GC.Collect();  // call twice for good measure
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();